# After use a API I was not to get the data from the API

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function modo() {
  moka = document.getElementById("sub").value;
  http = new XMLHttpRequest;
  http.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users/" + moka);
  http.send();
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readystatechange == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      df = JSON.parse(this.value);
      document.getElementById("we").innerHTML = df.data.first_name;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="we">Default text</p>
<input id="in">
<button onclick="modo()" id="sub">Submit</button>
```

Here I was use to API to get the data from the API. But the above code wasn't give me proper output.

Answer (score 0):

use `readyState === 4`
and your you're not taking correct input value

please find following snippet for reference

```js
function modo() {
  moka = document.getElementById("in").value;
  http = new XMLHttpRequest;
  http.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users/" + moka);
  http.send();
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      df = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
      console.log(http.responseText)

      document.getElementById("we").innerHTML = df.data.first_name;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="we">Default text</p>
<input id="in">
<button onclick="modo()" id="sub">Submit</button>
```

Comment: i guess it's better to change `document.getElementById("sub")` by document.getElementById("in")`because actually it's not refer to input field. With this u don't have to add `data[0]`

Comment: true missed that :), updating answer

Comment: Also it's possible to keep `this` instead of `http` for `http.responseText` :D

Comment: By the seen of above code I was mistakenly do the 'readystatechange' instead of 'readystate'. After that I was changed my code & correct it. But the problem wasn't solved. In addition when I was copy the code from above & run it then I was get proper output. So, my question is If two code is same then why one was give correct & another not given?

Answer (score 0):

You should take input value from element containing id="in"
and the use of the rest API is given in the official website.
Refer this link.

> https://reqres.in/

You have to use `http.readyState` instead of `readystatechange`

```js
function modo() {
  moka = document.getElementById("in").value;
  http = new XMLHttpRequest;
  http.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users/" + moka, true);
  http.onload = function(){
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      df = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
      document.getElementById("we").innerHTML = df.data.first_name;
    }
  };
  http.send();
  
}
```

```html
<p id="we">Default text</p>
<input id="in">
<button onclick="modo()" id="sub">Submit</button>
```

Thank you